# list of keyboard shortcuts for Files

Tags: pantheon-files, keyboard-shortcuts

i've searched here, reddit, launchpad and google but couldn't find the information. I wanted to know what shortcuts are available for Files. Checked keyboard shortcuts settings but none was listed. Appreciate if someone can point me to where it is.

Comment: I don't see one for deleting a file? EDIT: `<fn> + <delete>` on mac keyboard http://askubuntu.com/questions/155398/why-doesnt-the-delete-key-move-a-file-to-the-trash

Answer (score 7):

Ok, i searched deeper into the source code for pantheon-files and found these :)

```
 ("win.quit", {"<Ctrl>Q"});
 ("win.new_window", {"<Ctrl>N"});
 ("win.undo", {"<Ctrl>Z"});
 ("win.redo", {"<Ctrl><Shift>Z"});
 ("win.select_all", {"<Ctrl>A"});
 ("win.bookmark", {"<Ctrl>D"});
 ("win.find", {"<Ctrl>F"});
 ("win.tab::NEW", {"<Ctrl>T"});
 ("win.tab::CLOSE", {"<Ctrl>W"});
 ("win.tab::NEXT", {"<Ctrl>Page_Down"});
 ("win.tab::PREVIOUS", {"<Ctrl>Page_Up"});
 ("win.view_mode::ICON", {"<Ctrl>1"});
 ("win.view_mode::LIST", {"<Ctrl>2"});
 ("win.view_mode::MILLER", {"<Ctrl>3"});
 ("win.zoom::ZOOM_IN", {"<Ctrl>plus", "<Ctrl>equal"});
 ("win.zoom::ZOOM_OUT", {"<Ctrl>minus"});
 ("win.zoom::ZOOM_NORMAL", {"<Ctrl>0"});
 ("win.show_hidden", {"<Ctrl>H"});
 ("win.refresh", {"<Ctrl>R", "F5"});
 ("win.go_to::HOME", {"<Alt>Home"});
 ("win.go_to::TRASH", {"<Alt>T"});
 ("win.go_to::NETWORK", {"<Alt>N"});
 ("win.go_to::SERVER", {"<Alt>C"});
 ("win.go_to::UP", {"<Alt>Up"});
 ("win.go_to::FORWARD", {"<Alt>Right"});
 ("win.go_to::BACK", {"<Alt>Left"});
 ("win.info::HELP", {"F1"});
 ("win.info::ABOUT", {"F3"});
```

Comment: There are few more which are not handled by this part of the code e.g.

Comment: There are one or two more which are not handled by this part of the code e.g. "F2" for rename,  "Ctrl-L" for focus path bar, "Space" for activate.  An accessible list would be a good idea.

Comment: Is there a way to show/hide the sidebar without editing dconf directly?

Answer (score 2):

There is now a list of Files shortcuts at https://github.com/elementary/files/wiki/shortcuts