# Shortcut to focus on file-chooser dialog - CTRL-L doesn't work

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files

Been using Juno for a week; love the experience of NOT even attempting any customization - except for 3 keyboard shortcuts  I had to :) one thing that I am finding difficult is in file-chooser dialog (eg: extract archive; save as from browser etc), I have to use the mouse to get the focus to path/location bar. 90% of the time, I need to change from previous folder I was in, the way I work. In Files application, CTRL-L works perfectly; but I am unable to find a shortcut for this in these instances. I have checked documentation and [list of keyboard shortcuts for Files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-for-files)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, only the pathbar of the filechooser is supplied by Files, the rest (including keypress handling) is the standard Gtk filechooser so I am not sure this can be fixed. However, the intention is to use the NativeFileChooser interface to have the whole filechooser supplied by Files in which the shortcut will work.

I have raised an issue on the Files issue reporting page about it.